# Why I am not able to login on two smartphones?

Tags: google-account

What is the meaning that I an not able to login on another device?
I am sure that user and pwd are correct but on the second device it give me this message "user/password are not correct".

I try to set the smartphone with another account and it is easy to do that

I regularly use my account on the smartphone and on the pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of attempts the problem was the two step verification!

I was trying to login a HTC Desire with android 2.2 while my account has teo step verification so I was not able to setup the account (I do not know I on last version of Android is it possible to login with two step verification).

I solved:

- stop "two step verification"
- login on the smartphone
- set "two step verification"

Answer (score 0):

Having two phones logged into the same Google account works perfectly fine. If it tells you the username or password are incorrect, then most likely one of them is incorrect. In particular, if you're using different soft keyboards on the two phones, take extra care when typing punctuation characters and numbers: they could be in different places on different keyboards, so you could type the wrong one without realising it.

Comment: The user and the password are corrects. I typed them a lot of time and I also copyed them from the message app so they must be correct